# Multiplying two complex numbers in Scheme

Tags: math, scheme, complex-numbers

I have data representation of complex numbers, but I don't know how to multiply two complex numbers. Maybe, someone can help me?

```
(define (complex-num a b) 
      (cons a b))
(define (real x) 
      (car x)) 
(define (imag x) 
      (cdr x))
```

Comment: You don't know the mathematical formula, or you don't know how to express it in Scheme?

Comment: It's high school math, if you need help with that you should go to [math.se].

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388802/multiply-two-complex-numbers

Comment: @Barmar Curriculas vary from country to country.

Comment: @soegaard Maybe, but basic math like this has to be taught at some point. How can any educational institution consider their math curriculum acceptable without teaching complex numbers. In any case, if he didn't learn it in school, [so] is not the place to fill in the gap.

Comment: @barmar In most countries the institutions don’t have a choice. The curriculum is fixed on a nation wide basis. Now as everything else math topics taught changes over time. Here (Denmark) analysis have been reduced in favor of more statistical topics (such as chi squared and binomial tests). The rationale being that the general public has a greater need for a basic grasp of statistics than a knowledge of complex numbers. Of course this means the first thing taught at university math causes is complex numbers ;-)

Comment: Just saying that Scheme already has a builtin complex number type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to multiply two complex numbers

```
(a + bi) * (c + di) = (a + bi) * c + (a + bi) * di
                    = ac + bci  + adi + bdii
                    = ac + bci + adi - bd     (here we use that i*i = -1)
                    = ac-bd + (bc+ad)i
```

If we put `z1=a+bi` and `z2=c+di` then we can translate this to Scheme:

```
(define (multiply z1 z2)
  (let ([a (real z1)]
        [b (imag z1)]
        [c (real z2)]
        [d (imag z2)])
    (complex-num ..compute ac-bd..  ..compute bc+ad.. )))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (complex-mult a b)
  (make-rectangular (- (* (real-part a) (real-part b)) (* (imag-part a) (imag-part b)))
                    (+ (*(real-part a) (imag-part b)) (*(real-part b) (imag-part a)))))
```

e,g:

```
]=> (complex-mult 2+3i 5+2i)

 ;Value: 4+19i

]=> (complex-mult -i +i)

;Value: 1
```